# Is there any way to access device data using the Square Connect API?

Tags: square-connect

I'm attempting to generate a sales report using the Connect API (V2) and I'd like to see the breakdown of sales by device. There is no /devices endpoint and I don't see any mention of devices in any of the responses for the other endpoints (locations, transactions, etc.).

Does anyone know if there is any way to retrieve this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v2 of the Connect API does not currently return device data in any endpoint responses. I've filed a feature request with the API engineering team.

In the meantime, `Payment` objects returned by the v1 [List Payments](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#get-payments) endpoint *do* include a `device` field which includes the `name` of the device used to process the payment (if any). v1 endpoints are still supported, and your application can communicate with them just as it does with v2 endpoints.

Comment: I'll look into this option. Thanks!

Comment: Is your feature request publicly available? I'd be interested in keeping tabs on it as I don't think the Payment approach is going to work for my use case.

Comment: Unfortunately no, we do not currently publish outstanding feature requests. However, I will file a second feature request for _that_. :)

Could you elaborate on why the v1 approach doesn't work for your use case? It could help direct work on the v2 implementation.

Comment: Ideally, I'd be able to make a request like `GET /devices/[device_id]/payments` in order to retrieve _only_ the data I'm after. 

As it stands, I'd have to make a number of wide-ranging requests (_all_ payments), manually filter out the items I'm interested in and then make more requests using the link header in order to retrieve the remaining items I'm interested in. 

Hopefully that's clear/coherent/useful. :)

Comment: Just following-up, as I did end up giving the /payments approach a try. While it does work, albeit with a good deal of data munging and recursion, it's _incredibly_ slow - on the order of ~5 minutes to fetch and transform all orders since the beginning of the year.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I've reported this performance issue to the team.